# Why the manually added .so file in libs is automatically deleted by running the Android project?

Tags: android, android-library

I have an Android project A, with ndk and jni features.
It also links to another library project B.

In order to make things simpler, I remove the linked library project B,
and add the compiled .jar file and its .so files in /libs from B.

I put a line
System.loadLibrary("libfromB.so");

Now I clean and rebuild the project A. All is fine.
I find that every time I run the project, libfromB.so in /libs is deleted.
So it will complain:
02-21 17:47:26.493: E/AndroidRuntime(24086): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load fromB from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.android.askquestion.app-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.android.askquestion.app-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null

However, I see some Android projects from open source, they have some .so files put in /libs, and they are not deleted automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You should not put your .so files directly under the libs/ directory, but rather under an architecture appropriate subdirectory, for example

```
project/libs/armeabi/libfromB.so
```

It is possible that if your IDE believes your project has native code, it might be running an NDK build subsystem which is cleaning that directory.

System.loadLibrary() takes a short library name, not a filename.  So if your library is called "libfromB.so" you should use

```
System.loadLibrary("fromB");
```